# Pass control from one controller to other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

I am looking to fetch articles from RSS through my rails app. I have a web page which has a button that performs scraping of these articles. There is a User and Article model, and I have defined controller for scraping of these articles. These scraping controller should fetch the values from RSS feed and pass the values to Article controller.

I am new to rails and am not sure on how to perform this operation. Below is what I have done so far.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to rss_importer_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:author, :title, :summary, :url, :date, :image, :user_id)
    end
end

class RssImportersController < ApplicationController
  def scrape
    url = 'http://tviview.abc.net.au/rss/category/abc1.xml'
    open(url) do |rss|
      feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
      feed.items.each do |item|
        article_path(author => nil, title => item.title, summary => item.description,
                 source => item.link, date => item.pubDate, image => nil)

      end
    end
  end


end
```

In routes.rb -

```
  resources :rss_importers
```

This is my view -

```
<div class="btn-group pull-left" role="group">
  <%= link_to 'Scrape Articles', rss_importer_path ,class: "btn btn-default" %>
</div>
<br> <br>

<h1>All Articles</h1>

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
<%= render partial: 'index_article', locals: {article: article} %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using a controller for doing the scraping. You could create a service class and just call that from the article controller.

In app/services/rss_importer.rb:

```
class ImportRss
  def call(params)
    #Import code here
   end
end
```

Then in your article controller:

```
def create
  result = ImportRss.new.call(params)
  #Rest of your codes
end
```

Here is a good blog post on how to use service classes: http://adamniedzielski.github.io/blog/2014/11/25/my-take-on-services-in-rails/

Comment: This seems cool Tom. I was looking to scrape from a few RSS feeds as well as json. Could you please recommend me a design approach if I follow service approach? I am not sure of this in rails.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to help with that due to a limited understanding of what you're trying to accomplish. However, the blog post I linked has been very helpful for me when designing these types of features. Depending on what you're trying to do and how complicated each json feed / RSS feed is, you could just create a service for each so you can call them independently of each other. You could also build a parent class for these services that calls them all or decides which one to call based on the parameters provided.

Comment: Can't I concatenate the list of articles inside scrape method and pass the list of articles to create method of article which saves it as array of articles? I do not need service in that case.